# PHP function return / print speed

Tags: php, performance, optimization

I have one part of my application on the server which must return as fast as possible and right now is taking between 0.5 sec and 1.8 sec which is not even part of the computation.  What I mean by this is (using microtime) I have timed each part of the processes and the mysql calls and calculations take less than 0.2 secs every time but returning and printing add the additional second.  What can I do to make this as fast as possible since right now this is unacceptably slow?

There are two possible things I could think of: the data is built inside a function and a large array is returned as the value so it might be faster to simply print instead of return.  The second thing is I think there is an issue with the php print buffer.  When I break up the text I print into tinier chunks I see each chunk prints immediately (~0.00002 sec) except one will take all the extra time of about 0.5-1.5 secs which is where I think the print buffer has filled up and has to do a bunch of extra work.  Is there any way to fix this?

Some details: the text which is being printed is about 150Kb in size, I am not using flush or the ob_ functions but I had done experiments with them which did not seem to make a difference, and I am not using memcached. I understand that echo is faster than print because it is a statement and not a function call but how big of a difference could this make?  Since print will return the text which it prints will the larger text take much longer in print?

Comment: Could you give an example? As it doesn't seem to be the problem, make one up that doesn't do all the database stuff and calculations, just hardcode some strings and show us how you send it to the user, and when it starts getting slow. We can repeat the test, check if we see the same, etc. Kinda hard to say what's going on like this.

Comment: Maybe some throttling in PHP engine? Did you try to raise memory use? (I wonder how big is that text)

Comment: I have taken out the actual calculations and just had it print the things and still have the same time issues.  It is a lot of text like 150KB of text printed out.  I have raised memory but that didn't help.  I could try to raise it further...

Comment: install xdebug on server and profile your code. http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler It's a very powerful tool for analazing what happens inside your program.

Comment: How do you "print" the text ? using print ? echo ? only one or several ? do you use ob_start/flush do you have apc enabled ? memcached ?

Comment: I call print about three times, I do not use ob_start and flush, or use memcached.  I did experiment with flush and it didn't seem to help.  When I did the other experiment I described I chuncked the text into small pieces and called many prints, all of which were very fast except for one which would be about a second.  Answers to this question can also just be in general about how to make print go faster in php and about how php does return speed.

Comment: Do you use an associative array for the index?

Comment: Actually that's very strange what you experience. I just tried $a=str_repeat('test ', 10000000); print $a; and it took only 0.03 seconds for a file weighted over 40MB. It doesn't seem to be a problem with print, maybe the problem lies somewhere else. I would really love to see your actual code.

Comment: yeah same here... show some code ^^

Comment: Check the data you're pulling. It is possible that it's flawed somewhere. Please try to measure the actual size of the string, (maybe there are some empty or null chars, that take forever to process but never get printed. Just try strlen($a) to see the actual size of the string.

Comment: @hackartist:  please update the question with the requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 2):

> but returning and printing add the additional second

As per the comments this seems very strange. Given the nature of the application my thoughts are:

> the data is built inside a function and a large array is returned as the value

Why are you defering output like this? Large arrays are a big performance problem in PHP (NB Dan Lee: numerical as well as associative). But the hit is in adding elements / referencing individual elements - moving the array around is not an issue.

Why not send the data to the output buffer earlier?

> I think the print buffer has filled up

Seems very unlikely.

> I do not use ob_start and flush

Then do so - for preference with the gz handler.